# Nested Lists C# with Dynamic variable names

Tags: c#

I have a dynamic set of ID's I would like to add to a List of Lists as the list name so I can reference them later for look ups and I am not sure how I can set the list name equal to the ID I pulled from the database.

```
public List<List<int>> GetAllLists(string sGuid)
{
    List<List<int>> lRespondents = new List<List<int>>();
    SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString);
    StringBuilder sSQL = new StringBuilder();
    sSQL.Append("SELECT Demographic_Answers.ID FROM Demographic_Answers ");
    sSQL.Append("LEFT JOIN Demographic_Questions ON Demographic_Answers.Demogrpahic_ID = Demographic_Questions.ID ");
    sSQL.Append("WHERE Demographic_Questions.Survey_ID = '" + sGuid + "' ");
    SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(sSQL.ToString());
    sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
    sqlCon.Open();
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader sqlDR = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlDR.Read())
        {
            List<int> sub = new List<int>(); //Dynamic Name here sub = sqlDR.GetInt32(0).ToString
            sub = getRespondentList(sqlDR.GetInt32(0).ToString()); // Dynamic Name here. Sub should = sqlDR.GetInt32(0).ToString
        }
    }
    catch
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        sqlCon.Close();
    }

    return lRespondents;
}
```

the name sub in the code should be the `sqlDR.GetInt32(0).ToString()`.
Thanks!

Comment: `List<List<int>>` - that sucks. Create a proper, strongly typed data model instead.

Comment: What about if I do a Dictionary<key, List<int> that might work

Comment: Don't create your SQL by concatting strings, you're leaving yourself wide open for SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you I normally don't this is just a internal report writer for me to use only. But thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it sorry for the quick answer:

```
    public Dictionary<int, List<int>> GetAllLists(string sGuid)
    {
        Dictionary<int, List<int>> lRespondents = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
        SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString);
        StringBuilder sSQL = new StringBuilder();
        sSQL.Append("SELECT Demographic_Answers.ID FROM Demographic_Answers ");
        sSQL.Append("LEFT JOIN Demographic_Questions ON Demographic_Answers.Demogrpahic_ID = Demographic_Questions.ID ");
        sSQL.Append("WHERE Demographic_Questions.Survey_ID = '" + sGuid + "' ");
        SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(sSQL.ToString());
        sqlCom.Connection = sqlCon;
        sqlCon.Open();
        int iKeyName = 0;
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader sqlDR = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlDR.Read())
            {
                iKeyName = sqlDR.GetInt32(0);
                List<int> sub = new List<int>(); //Dynamic Name here sub = sqlDR.GetInt32(0).ToString
                sub = getRespondentList(sqlDR.GetInt32(0).ToString()); // Dynamic Name here. Sub should = sqlDR.GetInt32(0).ToString

                lRespondents.Add(iKeyName, sub);
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            sqlCon.Close();
        }

        return lRespondents;
    }
```

Comment: A `Dictionary` can be appropriate depending on the full usage but PLEASE look at and follow the comment Servy made on your question. Don't use a `StringBuilder` to build out your query. More on Sql injection [here](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5DP0N1P76E.html)

Comment: Thank you I normally don't this is just a internal report writer for me to use only. But thank you!